# DataFrame pop function removing wanted values in Nest Dictionary

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, nested

I have a DataFrame that has a nested dict within a column. I am removing the nested values and creating a column for each associated key. When using the pop function on `pricings` it removes values that are wanted. I wish to keep the `'1 color', '2 color', '3 color', '4 color', '5 color', '6 color'.`

The nested dict looks like this, with column name variations

```
{'name': 'printing on a DARK shirt',
 'pricings': {'1 color': [{'max': 47, 'min': 1, 'price': 100.0},
   {'max': 71, 'min': 48, 'price': 40.25},
   {'max': 143, 'min': 72, 'price': 2.8},
   {'max': 287, 'min': 144, 'price': 2.5}],
  '2 color': [{'max': 47, 'min': 1, 'price': 200.0},
   {'max': 71, 'min': 48, 'price': 4.25},
   {'max': 143, 'min': 72, 'price': 3.8},
   {'max': 287, 'min': 144, 'price': 3.5}],
  '3 color': [{'max': 47, 'min': 1, 'price': 300.0},
   {'max': 71, 'min': 48, 'price': 5.25},
   {'max': 143, 'min': 72, 'price': 4.8},
   {'max': 287, 'min': 144, 'price': 4.5}],
  '4 color': [{'max': 47, 'min': 1, 'price': 400.0},
   {'max': 71, 'min': 48, 'price': 6.25},
   {'max': 143, 'min': 72, 'price': 5.8},
   {'max': 287, 'min': 144, 'price': 5.5}],
  '5 color': [{'max': 47, 'min': 1, 'price': 500.0},
   {'max': 71, 'min': 48, 'price': 7.5},
   {'max': 143, 'min': 72, 'price': 7.0},
   {'max': 287, 'min': 144, 'price': 6.6}],
  '6 color': [{'max': 47, 'min': 1, 'price': 600.0},
   {'max': 71, 'min': 48, 'price': 8.5},
   {'max': 143, 'min': 72, 'price': 8.0},
   {'max': 287, 'min': 144, 'price': 7.6}]}}
```

The code I'm using looks like this

```
df2 = (pd.concat({i: pd.DataFrame(x) for i, x in df1.pop('variations').items()})
                 .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
                 .join(df1 , how='left', lsuffix='_left', rsuffix='_right')
                 .reset_index(drop=True))
```

The output is as follows, with the new column name pricing added.

```
    [{'max': 47, 'min': 1, 'price': 20.0},
 {'max': 71, 'min': 48, 'price': 4.25},
 {'max': 143, 'min': 72, 'price': 3.8},
 {'max': 287, 'min': 144, 'price': 3.5}]
```

If its not clear in the DataFrame the actual list of colors `'1 color', '2 color', '3 color', '4 color', '5 color', '6 color'.` ranges has fallen off. This is important and the portion I want most. the colors have not created there own column so we are clear.

Comment: Can you separate out the code? That’s a complex line, how can it be debugged?

Comment: I can try to break it out further but its a for loop that joins another DataFrame together.

Comment: It’s just to make things simpler for us. An explanation of what it’s doing might help.